# Most time-efficient way to implement a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix

What is the most time-efficient way to implement a 2D array in C++? I am concerned with: insert, delete, and look-up.

I have read about these two methods:

1. `vector<vector<int>>` - Nested vectors
2. `vector<vector<int>*>` - Vector with pointers to other vectors

I found the first option to be easy to implement, but is there another method that is more time-efficient?

Comment: This technique `vector<dataType> matrix[size]` you can follow.

Comment: You might be interested in a linear algebra library like [Blaze](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze) or [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

1. Create a class, `Matrix`.
2. Carefully define the interface so you don't expose the internal data structure details.
3. Start with using one of the methods of capturing the data. I would recommend starting with a `std::vector` -- a 1D array.
4. If you run into any performance or maintenance issues, change the internal data to use another strategy.

Answer (score 2):

To initialize that matrix for size `MxN`, all you have to do is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<dataType>> MyMat = std::vector<std::vector<dataType>>(M,std::vector<dataType>(N,0));
```

However, I have to mention that this is a HORRIBLE way to create matrices. You're killing performance by writing a matrix that way. This is because your processor uses something called `vectorization` to multiply multiple numbers together in one instruction when you do matrix multiplication, and you make it harder for the processor when you do this. Besides, this will kill cache locality, because the different rows (or columns) will not be contiguous in memory, making everything slower probably hundreds of times.

Consider reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) if you're interested.

The right way to do this is to create a class (probably) with a vector:

```
std::vector<dataType> MyMat(M*N,0);
```

Then you create an accessor that will access elements by element:

```
dataType& getElement(int i, int j)
{
    return MyMat[M*i+j];
}
```

This way you get the best performance. Of course, there's way more details on performance, but this is enough to answer your question.

Btw, you're not supposed to do matrix operations yourself. In the best case, if you're a professional high-performance dev, you're supposed to use some LAPACK implementation to do the matrix operations for you (like he guys from [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) did).